# MSBI SSRS List Property

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-tablix

I am creating a report using MSBI SSRS. i choose list and inside list i added 2 tables. I used list for splitting the tables according to id. The problem i am facing now is that if there exist repeated/ same values in tables, I am only able to see the value once (as a unique value in the table), but i would like to display all the values present in the table rather than hiding the repeated values. I tried finding the property of the list but I am unable to display all the values which I am able to see while executing MDX.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only provide a general description. you get a general answer.

If you have a lower granularity column, just add that column to you group by inside your List.

Or add a rownumber to your dataset, if possible, and group by the rownumber instead.

Comment: I added the column which i wanted to group by inside my list, but for the rest of the columns, if every row of the column has same values, it shows only one value at the fisrt row of that column and rest of the rows are blank till the next change in the value of the row.